# Issue setting production port number - (RuntimeError) expected the PORT environment variable to be set

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

I'm deploying on aws with edeliver. The deploys run fine, but when I try to access the site in the console with `curl localhost:8888`, I get a `connection refused` error.

If I try to start the app with `./rel/bin/app_name console`, I get a `(RuntimeError) expected the PORT environment variable to be set`. However my `config/prod.exs` looks like this.

```
use Mix.Config

config :elixir_deploy, ElixirDeployWeb.Endpoint,
  load_from_system_env: true,
  http: [port: 8888],
  ssl: false,
  url: [host: "example.com", port: 80],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json"

config :logger, level: :info

import_config "prod.secret.exs"
```

What am I missing here? It works if I set a `PORT=8888` before the manual start, but I'd rather start automatically with edeliver

Comment: Are you sure you're not overwriting the http port config later in the config?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, the only other lines are `use Mix.Config` in the beginning, `config :logger, level: :info`, and `import_config "prod.secret.exs"` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `load_from_system_env` to `false` (or just remove that line). When it's `true`, Phoenix's default generated `endpoint.ex` will use the value of the `PORT` environment variable, and if it's not found, it'll raise an error.

```
if config[:load_from_system_env] do
  port = System.get_env("PORT") || raise "expected the PORT environment variable to be set"
  {:ok, Keyword.put(config, :http, [:inet6, port: port])}
else
  {:ok, config}
end
```

<sup>[Source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/37a8dea7bbce6523933fff5ae52e0c77e8fc0228/installer/templates/phx_web/endpoint.ex#L50-L55)</sup>

Comment: I was too busy  trying to get it to work on the next line. Couldn't see the forrest for the trees. Thanks.